# How to run bash logical operators from python

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I'm trying to execute:

```
    actual = subprocess.run(['echo 123 | ./ft_ssl md5 -s ' + data + ' -p'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    actual = actual.stdout.decode('utf-8')
```

and after that variable `actual` equals `"123 | ./ft_ssl md5 -s fuck -p\n"`.

Python run only echo for all the input and ignore `|` operation.

Help, please, what i have to do to run two commands with this logical operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid `echo` altogether. Piping can be simulated here by passing the `echo` argument to the stdin of the call to `./ft_ssl`

```
actual = subprocess.Popen(['./ft_ssl', 'md5', '-s', data, '-p'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = actual.communicate(b'123')
```

See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) for more details about [`communicate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)